# Auto open the info window closest to map center in google maps

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to detect the map marker nearest to the map center and open it automatically?

I haven't seen anything in the documentation, and I haven't found a plug in, but I was wondering if there was something I haven't found.

+EDIT+ I'm using V3 with a KML layer and infobox.js to style the pop up. At the moment I'm using a click listener to open the box, but I would like to have some way of auto-opening either one, or all of the infoboxes

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    showInContentWindow(kmlEvent.latLng, kmlEvent.featureData.name);
    });  

 function showInContentWindow(position, text) {
 var content = "<div style='color:white; max-width:130px; height:18px; font-size:24px, '>" + text +  "</div>";
 var infowindow = new InfoBox({
 content: content, 
 position: position,
 })
 infowindow.open(map);
 }
```

Comment: Of course it is possible. What have you tried?  What does your code look like?  Are you using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)?

Comment: I'm using V3 with a KML layer and infobox.js to style the pop up. At the moment I'm using a click listener to open the box, but I would like to have some way of auto-opening either one, or all of the infoboxes.

My code is in the above edit

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do it with KmlLayer, that only gives you access to the featureData on a click. But you can either import your KML into [FusionTables](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables) and access it that way (with a query) or use a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/))

Comment: I actually have geoxml3 ready to go, so I can easily change to generating the map that way. 
What would I need to do to go about triggering the infoboxes?

Comment: process through the markers, find the one closest to the center, trigger the click event on it.

Comment: And that sadly is where I think my talent will run out. But would there be a way to open all infoboxes on pageload in geoxml3?

Comment: Sure. And if you posted (more of) your code, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Right, I'll get geoxml3 up and running and come back. Thanks for the pointers!